# Error in WGS84 to Mercator coordinate transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, ellipsoid, web-mercator

I'm trying to convert the (lat,lon) of WGS84 into Mercator (x,y). Below I've listed all the relevant information given in the file.

```
Datum="WGS84"
Ellipsoid="WGS84"
grid_mapping_name = "mercator"
Conventions=CF-1.6

Right_longitude=110
Left_longitude=44.5

Upper_latitude=45.5
Lower_latitude=-10

Nominal_Altitude(km) = 36000.0 #Height of INSAT-3DR geostationary satellite (in km)

Central_longitude=77.25
Central_latitude=0

False_Easting=0
Flase_Northing=0

Semi_Major_Axis=6378137.0 #in m
Semi_Minor_Axis=6356752.3142 #in m
standard_parallel = 17.75

x_left=-3473242.7 #in m
x_right=3473242.7 #in m
y_upper=5401854.4 #in m
y_lower=-1058893.7 #in m
```

**How data is there in the file**

In the data, we have a separate 1-D arrays of X and Y, each of which is evenly spaced. But nothing is explicitly given on how to convert (X,Y) of the projection into (lat,lon) of everyday usage. I've trying this problem since one month but with some erroneous results.

**Below is what I've tried till now**

1- **Formula 1**

**x(lon)=R × (lon-central_longitude)**

**y(lat)=R × ln(tan(π/4+lat/2))**

Converting Lower_latitude->y_lower, Upper_latitude->y_upper, Left_longitude->x_left,Right_longitude->x_right using the formula above, I compare them to the corresponding values pre-given to us, the error is 4-5%.

For example, x(Right_longitude)=x(110)=3641633.848 #in m, but x_right=3473242.7 #in m. So there's an error.

2- **Formula 2** (Generalized form of formula 1)

a= semi-major axis
b=semi-minor axis
e= eccentricity = sqrt(1-(b/a)^2)
c(lat)= curvature = a/sqrt([1-e^2]×[sin(lat)^2])

**x(lat,lon)= c(lat) × cos(lat) × cos(lon-central_longitude)**

**y(lat,lon)= c(lat) × cos(lat) × sin(lon-central_longitude)**

Here, doing the same comparison, the error is 3-4%.

The error bar is too high for me to proceed ahead and I can't find out why am I getting the error. Is there any other conversion formula that I should try?

Comment: why not use an existing projection library, rather than re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I'm doing it in python. Is there any library I can use there? @IanTurton

Comment: try to use Pyproj library

Comment: I see the typo “ Flase_Northing=0” does this matter in your code?

Comment: I'd have to look up the ellipsoidal Mercator equations but yours don't seem complicated enough. However, you've missed the 'standard_parallel = 17.75' in the description as well. Try downloading guidance note 7-2 (under support documents) from https://epsg.org and try Mercator Variant B.

Comment: @mkennedy Update: - Well, I'm late in replying but I used the formula given in the description. There's an error of around 5% which is significant. In fact, its results have minor difference with the results from formula 1 (written in the post). But at least I've used the standard parallel in this formula. Could you suggest how to do it through pyproj? I'm confused about the codes that I'd use. WGS84->(Easting-Northing coordinates) is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: @HansErren No, False_Northing doesn't matter in my code. It's set to 0.